# Gremlin filter out going edge based on incoming edge while traversing a path

Tags: gremlin

I am trying to traverse a graph using gremlin in which selection of outgoing edge depends on incoming edge, For example, I have a graph

[image]

So here Path A->B->C is valid because arrives.time < (departs.time 
and path A->B->D is invalud because arrives.time > departs.time

```
g.V().has("name","A").outE().inV().outE().filter(values("time",lte(???))
```

Any pointers on how can I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `where` step with `by` modulator:

```
g.V().has("name","A")
  .outE("Arrives").as("arrives").inV()
  .outE("Departs").where(lte("arrives")).by("time").inV()
```